# Word Ladder - Homophones

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, homophone

This word ladder is a pair of homophones. Complete the riddle (I took inspiration from Duck's homophone riddles*) and then do the word ladder with the words you got from the riddle.

```
One of them can change the mood,
The other can decide
One of them can make it bright
The other is a dilemma
```

Word Ladder Rules:

- You can alter letters, one at a time, and each intermediate word must be a valid word in dictionary.com.
- You may not rearrange letters or make two words: ie. office->off ice.
- You may not use a program or online solver.
- Use the minimum number of moves

*I've been reading up on posts after I was "living under a rock" with the whole vowelburger thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is:

> Whether and Weather

One of them can change the mood

> Maybe you are under the weather or it is a cloudy day

One of them can decide

> You can decide **whether** or not to do something.

One of them can make it bright

> The weather can make it bright with the sun

The other is a dilemma

> A dilemma is where you can decide on something

Word ladder:

> WEATHER
> LEATHER
> LEACHER
> PEACHER
> PEACHED
> POACHED
> COACHED
> COACTED
> COASTED
> COASTER
> CHASTER
> CHATTER
> CHITTER
> WHITTER
> WHETTER
> WHETHER

Comment: Right on! Nice job. +1 :-)